# Reading multiple html pages with rvest in parallel

Tags: r, foreach, rvest, doparallel

I am attempting to scrape values from a webpage using `rvest` in parallel with `foreach` and `doParallel`. Specifically, I am using a real estate property identifier called a TMK to retrieve the property's census tract number from the website.

In the sample code below, the `foreach` loop gives the desired results (a vector containing tract numbers) when run with `%do%`, but not with `%dopar%`.

```
require(rvest); require(foreach); require(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 4)

# sample input values used to generate html
tmklist <- c(91136088, 73006073, 92023027, 45061064)

# read html for each TMK
# DOES NOT PRODUCE DESIRED RESULT WHEN USED WITH %dopar%
tmkhtml <- foreach(i = seq_along(tmklist)) %do% {
  read_html(paste0(paste0('http://gis.hicentral.com/pubwebsite/TMKDetails.aspx?tmk=', tmklist[[i]]),'&lyrLst=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|13|0|15|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|lblsaerial2008&unit=0000&address='))
}

# scrape census tract number from html page
# loop returns vector of chr(0) if %dopar% used instead of %do%
tract.num <- list()

for(i in 1:length(tmkhtml)){
  tract.num[[i]] <- html_text(html_nodes(tmkhtml[[i]], '#lblTrackNumber'))   
}
```

I've (maybe incorrectly) deduced that the parallel backend is to blame, but I've used it many times before in other applications and can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: This is a good question but at the same time just a warning -- be careful not to get your IP banned by the sites you're scraping for too many simultaneous requests. It's happens a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Its might be that when you try and read each page using more than one instance of R, all of them need the `rvest` package to use `rvest::read_html`. Try loading the library in the `foreach` such as:

```
# read html for each TMK
tmkhtml <- foreach(i = seq_along(tmklist)) %dopar% {
library(rvest)
  read_html(paste0(paste0('http://gis.hicentral.com/pubwebsite/TMKDetails.aspx?tmk=', tmklist[[i]]),'&lyrLst=0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|13|0|15|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|lblsaerial2008&unit=0000&address='))
}
```